# Vim remove part of line in a file

Tags: vim, vi

I have a big file contains many lines in the following format,

```
<SomeString1>Key1</SomeString>
<SomeString2>Key2</SomeString>
<SomeString3>Key3</SomeString>
...
```

I want to remove the tags, and the output should look like,

```
 Key1
 Key2
 Key3
 ...
```

Algorithmically, I should write something like:

```
For all lines:
   Remove all string before character `>`
   Remove all string after character `</`
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use a replace [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
:%s/<[^>]*>//g
```

This will apply the `s` (substitution) command for each line (`%`) and remove all `<...>` sequences for the entire line (`g`).

There are many situations in which these commands come in handy, especially using regex. You can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

These two commands should do the trick:

```
:%s/<\w*>//
:%s/<\/\w*>//
```

The first replaces all the opening tags with nothing. The second replaces all the closing tags with nothing. `<\w*>` matches any number of alphanumeric characters between `<` and `>` and `<\/\w*>` matches any number of alphanumeric characters between `</` and `>`.

Edit: a simpler way:

```
:%s/<.\{-}>//g
```

Note that this:

```
:%s/<.*>//g
```

Won't work because the `*` is "greedy" and will match the whole line. `\{-}` is the non-greedy equivalent. Read more about greediness here: http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy